# django: where to put recurring query on list of model objects

Tags: python, django

I have `Product` as a model.

I am refactoring some code, and there is a recurring query spread all over the code base which needs replacement.

So I'd like to centralize this query, in order to encapsulate its logic.

I'd like something like

```
 <an_object>.get_uncompleted_products(products);
```

In this case, preserving existing code, `products` is already a result of a query (`products = Products.objects.filter(filter_expression)`)

This is just a convenience question, I know a possible answer, but where would you put `get_uncompleted_products()`, what could be a good"django-way" solution?

I was initially wanting to put it on the `Product` model. But I was thinking `Product` methods to work directly on a single model reference, thus the signature would need to be:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   @classmethod
   get_uncompleted_products(list)
```

I am not sure why this gives me the feeling to be not so appropriate. A possible alternative would be to put it into a utility module. I could also have it in the view module but it seems it's used profusely in other views as well so I'd prefer somewhere more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the 'django way' would be to define it as a custom manager method, instead of class method, which can be shared between different models with composition instead of inheritance in case of class methods.

```
from django.db import models

class ProductQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

      def get_uncompleted_products(self):
          ...

class ProductManager(models.Manager):

      def get_queryset(self):
          return ProductQueryset(self.model, using=self._db)

      def get_uncompleted_products(self):
          # defined twice to resolve queryset chaining issue with custom managers
          return self.get_queryset().get_uncompleted_products()

class Product(models.Model):

    ...
      objects = ProductManager()
```

Comment: You don't need to define a separate queryset since Django 1.7; just define the queryset, and set objects to `ProductQuerySet.as_manager()`.

Comment: @Daniel since i mostly use django with mongoengine, and in mongoengine manager always returns queryset. So my knowledge of managers in django is quite rusty. So thanks